# In Excel Finding maximum value across spreadsheets using Index

Tags: excel, indexing, comparison, max

I am trying to select a cell from another worksheet.  The first worksheet contains the Title (city) i'm searching and looking to go to another spreadsheet where the latest sales records are kept.   So for that city looking for the highest value and return the maximum value for specified city.  I am using the index because I have 4 different tabs to pull in Purchases, Debt, Inventory.  Trying to pull the highest value for each of those.

Any help would be appreciated.  I've tried `=INDEX('Sales Purchase'!K3:K89,MATCH(C3, MAX(IF('Sales Purchase'!A:A89=Summary!C2,'Sales Purchase'!B2:B89))),0)` and it is returning #N/A

[image]

Comment: `'Sales Purchase'!A:A89=Summary!C2` should be A2:A89

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your structure, but I tried as follows it works.
[image]